# How to count button clicks in RJSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, react-hooks, jsx

I have a simple counter app I am practicing. I have it setup so that each time Increase or Decrease is pressed, the count will change accordingly. But I want to count how many times each button is clicked in positive integers. My problem now is that whenever Count is below 0, numCount will subtract. Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

````
import './style.css';
import Count from './things.js';


export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const getColor = () => {
    if (count === 0) return '#112a42';
    return count < 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
  };

  const num =  (numCount) => {
    if (numCount >= 0) return numCount;
    if (numCount < 0) return numCount * - 1;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="main">
        <Count text="What's the count?"/>

        <h1 style={{ color: getColor() }} className="number">
          {count}
        </h1>

        <div className="buttons">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="decrease"
            onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}
          >
            Decrease
          </button>

          <button
            type="button"
            className="reset"
            onClick={() => setCount(0)}
          >
            Reset
          </button>

          <button
            type="button"
            className="increase"
            onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
          >
            Increase
          </button>
        </div>

        <p className="paragraph"> You clicked {num(count)} times</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: If you're trying to track how many times were clicked in total, shouldn't you just `count + 1` every time? Or are you trying to track a counter that is influenced by (but not directly reflective of) clicks? Is your goal actually to maintain a counter that can never drop below 0?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal verifiable example

- `React.useState` is used to count each `plus` and `minus` state.
- Counter is derived state and can be computed using `plus - minus`
- Total clicks is derived state and can be computed using `plus + minus`
- To reset, `setPlus(0)` and `setMinus(0)`

```js
function App() {
  const [plus, setPlus] = React.useState(0)
  const [minus, setMinus] = React.useState(0)
  function reset(event) {
    setPlus(0)
    setMinus(0)
  }
  return <div>
    <button type="button" onClick={_ => setMinus(minus + 1)} children="-" />
    {plus - minus}
    <button type="button" onClick={_ => setPlus(plus + 1)} children="+" />
    <br />
    total clicks: {plus + minus}
    <br />
    <button type="button" onClick={reset} children="reset" />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: What would I write if I wanted the "total clicks" not to reset? So the amount of clicks from the previous time I used the function would be ignored by the reset